# Can't find the error

Tags: visual-c++

This program is a nightmare, it wont even give me errors when ran, visual studios tells me nothing and i need some help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Textbook
{
private:
    char *aPtr;
    char *tPtr;
    int yearPub;
    int numPages;
    char bookType;
public:
    Textbook(char *, char *, int, int, char);
    void display();
    void operator=(Textbook&);
};

 Textbook::Textbook(char*string = NULL, char*string2 = NULL, int ypub = 0, int npages = 0, char btype = 'X')
{
aPtr = new char[strlen(string) +1];
strcpy(aPtr, string);

tPtr = new char[strlen(string2) +1];
strcpy(tPtr, string2);

yearPub = ypub;
numPages = npages;
bookType = btype;
}

void Textbook::display()
{
cout << "The name of the author is: " << *aPtr << endl;
cout << "The Title of the book is: " << *tPtr << endl;
cout << "The year it was published is: " << yearPub << endl;
cout << "The number of pages is: " << numPages << endl;
cout << "The initial of the title is: " << bookType << endl;
return;
}

void Textbook::operator=(Textbook& newbook)
{
if(aPtr != NULL) //check that it exists
    delete(aPtr);// delete if neccessary
aPtr = new char[strlen(newbook.aPtr) + 1];
strcpy(aPtr, newbook.aPtr);

if(tPtr != NULL) //check that it exists
    delete(tPtr); // delete if neccessary
tPtr = new char[strlen(newbook.tPtr) + 1];
strcpy(tPtr, newbook.tPtr);

yearPub = newbook.yearPub;
numPages = newbook.numPages;
bookType = newbook.bookType;
}


void main()
{
Textbook book1("sehwag", "Programming Methods", 2009, 200, 'H');
Textbook book2("Ashwin", "Security Implementation", 2011, 437, 'P');
Textbook book3;

book1.display();
book2.display();
book3.display();

book3 = book1;
book2 = book3;

book1.display();
book2.display();
book3.display();
}
```

im not sure if the problem lies in the default constructor but that's about the only thing i could think of, but im not sure at all on how to fix it.

Comment: What happens when you compile and run it ?

Comment: it says it needs to break, wont even list any errors

Comment: Did you try single-stepping through the code in the debugger ?

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer if you provide a title for your question that is more specific to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
cout << "The name of the author is: " << *aPtr << endl;
cout << "The Title of the book is: " << *tPtr << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << "The name of the author is: " << aPtr << endl;
cout << "The Title of the book is: " << tPtr << endl;
```

Also change:

```
aPtr = new char[strlen(string) +1];
strcpy(aPtr, string);
```

to:

```
if (string != NULL)
{
    aPtr = new char[strlen(string) +1];
    strcpy(aPtr, string);
}
else
{
    aPtr = new char[1];
    aPtr[0] = '\0';
}
```

and ditto for `tptr` and `string2`.

The reason you need this checking is because you have NULL as a default value for your two string inputs, so when you call the constructor with no arguments (as is the case with book3) these strings are just NULL pointers. Calling functions such as strlen or strcat with a NULL pointer will result in an exception as you have seen.

Ideally you should not be using C-style strings with C++ - use C++ `string`s instead - this will help to avoid problems such as the above.

Comment: i did but its still doing the same thing, gives me this error then asks to break

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5f38d540 (msvcr100d.dll) in Final C++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: What line are you at when you are single-stepping and you get the exception ?

Comment: im thinking its this line, because after it asks to break it says that char * is unasigned

Comment: aPtr = new char[strlen(string) +1];

Comment: Yep - that's because string is NULL when you try to create book3 - guess what happens when you call strlen with a NULL string as an argument ?

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick, although if u could add a little explanation to it itd be nice :)

Comment: OK - see additional comments in answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the default-parameters in the constructor.
You can't do those kind of operations with NULL-pointers.

```
Textbook book3;
```

crashes your program.

Comment: Specifically, you can't pass a null pointer to `strlen` or `strcpy`.

Comment: Exactly, I just looked in the reference. I should have elaborated more. Thanks.